# Python: Implementing a Map with Chaining

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

My assignment is to implement a map with chaining by creating a hash table with two lists, one called "slots" and one called "data. My code seems to work until the 'G' character. I can't quite pinpoint what is going on here and I have tried debugging.

```
class HashTable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 11
        self.slots = [None] * self.size
        self.data = [None] * self.size

    def put(self,key,data):
        hashvalue = self.hashfunction(key,len(self.slots))

        if self.slots[hashvalue] == None:
            self.slots[hashvalue] = list()
            self.slots[hashvalue].append(key)
            self.data[hashvalue] = list()
            self.data[hashvalue].append(data)
        else:
            if self.slots[hashvalue] != None:
                self.data[hashvalue].append(data)  #replace

    def hashfunction(self,key,size):
         return key%size


    def get(self,key):
        startslot = self.hashfunction(key,len(self.slots))

        data = None
        stop = False
        found = False
        position = startslot
        while self.slots[position] != None and not found and not stop:
            for index in range (len(self.slots[position])):
                if self.slots[position][index]== key:
                    found = True
                    data = self.data[position][index]
                    break
            position+1
            if position == startslot:
                stop = True
        return data

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __setitem__(self,key,data):
        self.put(key,data)

## TEST FOR HashTable
h = HashTable() # create new hash table

nums = [1, 3, 5, 50, 1000] # some keys
nums = nums + [ len(h.slots)*i for i in range(20)] # some keys that have same hash
vals = [ chr(x) for x in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')) ] # list of single letters from A to Z

# add key/values
for i in range(len(nums)):
    # print("adding (%d, %s)"%(nums[i],vals[i]),end=" ")
    h[nums[i]] = vals[i]

for i in range(len(nums)):
    key = nums[i]
    value = vals[i]
    gotValue = h[key]
    assert gotValue == value,"expected key: %d to lookup value: %s but got value %s instead " % (key, value, gotValue)

print("\nAll TESTS PASSED")
```

Comment: where is the error happening?

Answer (score 0):

**I found my issue**:

I forgot to add a line under:

```
if self.slots[hashvalue] != None:
```

that adds the key to the [hashvalue] of slots.
So now I have:

```
if self.slots[hashvalue] != None:
            self.slots[hashvalue].append(key)
            self.data[hashvalue].append(data)
```

It was adding the  data value to the corresponding list "data", but not the matching key value to the list "slots"